# JavaScript : how to embed HTML code, how to quote?

Tags: javascript, html, select

Given that I have a JavaScript section in my HTML page like :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
...
</script>
```

I am aware of the function :
document.write("Hello World") ;

But, how can I can include the following HTML :

```
<select name="database_subcollection" multiple="true" size="5" onsubmit="document.getElementById('MAIN').submit()">
```

If I write it like :

```
document.write('<select name="database_subcollection" multiple="true" size="5" onsubmit="document.getElementById('MAIN').submit()">') ;
```

It complains. So, I would like your help in overcoming this.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use document.write(). There are better ways to change the DOM. See [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) or appendChild() for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
document.write('<select name="database_subcollection" multiple="true" size="5" onsubmit="document.getElementById(\'MAIN\').submit()">');
```

You needed to escape `('MAIN')` with `\` eg `(\'MAIN\')` assuming containing quotes are single quotes.

#### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/umared)

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape (double) quote characters, by prefixing an escape character: `\`.

Possible ways to escape a double quote:

- `\"` (JavaScript)
- `\x22` (JavaScript)
- `&quot` (HTML attribute value / plain HTML)

Your example with single quotes didn't work, because the attribute contained a single quote. Replace the `'` in the attribute by `\'` or `&quot;` to solve it.

```
document.write('<select name="database_subcollection" multiple="true" size="5" onsubmit="document.getElementById(\'MAIN\').submit()">') ;
```

Comment: I would not use `&quot;` because that's a `"` which makes the attribute end there.

Comment: @pimvdb If `&quot;` is properly applied, your statement is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/kyHHj/

Comment: You're correct. I wouldn't have guessed that works. +1, I learn something new each day!

Answer (score 1):

Read the "Escaping characters" part of this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals
And I think it will all make sense.